# If condition is true then Jquery get values from 2 input fields, multiply the values and insert result in third input field

Tags: jquery

Based on this http://api.jquery.com/val/ trying to create code (get values from 2 input fields, multiply and insert result in third input field).

Placed sample here http://jsfiddle.net/KWEyG/1/

```
<td><input type="text" name="result[]" id='result' value="77"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="firstVal[]" id='firstVal' value="first"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="secondVal[]" id='secondVal' value="second"></td>
```

And then `jquery`

```
function displayVals() {
    var firstValue = $("#firstVal").val();
    var secondValue = $("#secondVal").val();

    $("#result").val(firstValue*secondValue);
}
$("input").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Default value for `result` is `77`. But with the code default value see `NaN`.

Added `if ( ($("#firstVal").val() > 0) && ($("#secondVal").val() != '') ) {`. Default value is ok, but no calculations.

What need to correct to get the script work?

**Update**

Based on advices get what is necessary

```
function displayVals() {

    if ( ($("#firstVal").val() > 0) && ($("#secondVal").val() != '') ) {

        var firstValue = $("#firstVal").val();
        var secondValue = $("#secondVal").val();

        $("#result").val(firstValue*secondValue);
    }
$("input").change(displayVals);
}

displayVals();
```

Comment: If you don't enter anything into the second box, its value will be `"second"`, not `""`, so the test `$("#secondVal").val() != ''` will fail.

Comment: I entered values in both (first and second) and no calculations. You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/KWEyG/3/

Comment: The `if` code should be inside the `displayVals()` function, not around the whole function definition and event binding code.

Comment: @Barmar: why comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Chris Because the existing answers seemed more pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were multiplying strings instead use integer values like below:

```
<td><input type="text" name="result[]" id='result' value="77"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="firstVal[]" id='firstVal' value=""></td>

<td><input type="text" name="secondVal[]" id='secondVal' value=""></td>
```

Edit:

```
 $("#check").click(function(){
if ( ($("#firstVal").val() > 0) && ($("#secondVal").val() != '') ) {
displayVals();
}else{
alert("insert a value");
}
```

})

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWEyG/5/)

Comment: Yes. But aim is to multiply only if condition is true. With your solution, for example change `value="6"` to `value=""`. And instead of default value `value="77"` see...

Comment: i have edited the post with if condition, see if this is your aim.

Comment: @Ram: You want to put the logic into the `displayVals` function rather than into a click function on the new button. Otherwise the validation doesn't occur when the change event is fired for a input element.

Answer (score 1):

See your code: 
You are multiplying a `String` with `String` which is a obvious result `NaN`

Second thing to understand is use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` before arithmetic calculation and then check for by `isNaN` method.

`$("#firstVal").val();` will result in attribute value of `value` in element `<input>` and here that is `first` (`String`).

Check by using alert:

```
function displayVals() {
var firstValue = $("#firstVal").val();
var secondValue = $("#secondVal").val();
alert(firstValue+' '+secondValue+(firstValue*secondValue));
}
```

But when you change both value to `number` it should work as `value` will be a number.

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` is inserted into `#result` because you call `displayVals();` at the end of your code-snippet. The function now tries to multiply `first` and `second` which of course returns `NaN` since you can't multiply strings.

Comment: Yes, understand regarding `NaN`. So added `if` (condition)